# Selenium C# The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

"  Message=A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:49803/session. The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."

So I have a handful of tests which work with Chrome. I am testing out on Edge (for now, the rest of the browsers later).

The method I am running which is failing is:
            public void Load(string Url, Browsers Browser)
        {
            this.Url = Url;
            this.Browser = Browser;

```
        IWebDriver driver;

        switch (Browser)
        {
            case Browsers.Edge:
                driver = new EdgeDriver(driverLocation);
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                break;
            case Browsers.Chrome:
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(driverLocation, options);
                break;
            case Browsers.Firefox:
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverLocation);
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                break;
            default:
                driver = new ChromeDriver(driverLocation);
                break;

        }
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        Driver = driver;
        driver.Url = this.Url;
    }
```

Where the browser passed in is edge.

```
                driver = new EdgeDriver(driverLocation);
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                break;
```

The browser loads, then I receive the error above.

I have checked my OS build (17763.437) and downloaded the latest WebDriver (Release 17134) cuz that is all there is. I see no info on Edge specific stuff I need. My search foo is pathetic however.

Help lease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver for Edge version 18, [which shipped with Windows 10 build 17763](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide), became a "feature on demand" for Windows, and is not generally downloadable as a separate download on the web. See the "Installation and Usage" section on the [Microsoft WebDriver documentation page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) for information on how to install and use it.

Comment: Ok cool. You helped me understand the bit "Windows Feature on Demand which ensures that it’s always up to date automatically and enables some new ways to get Microsoft WebDriver. To get started you will have to enable Developer Mode:
Go to Settings > Update and Security > For Developer and then select “Developer mode”." That I did not understand. So... having done that, how do I know WHERE the webdriver is or really, what is the correct driver constructor? (driver = new EdgeDriver(driverLocation);)

Comment: @user2919960 The default constructor (`driver = new EdgeDriver();`) will suffice. The driver is installed to `%WindowsDirectory%\System32`, if memory serves, though I may be misremembering. Additionally, the driver can be copied from that to any destination directory, but would be subject to the same update issues.